# How to return result of parent observables after applying filter on nested object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a database object named **orders** in firebase, which has the following structure
[image]

Now, I am trying to filter the results based on book title, to return the orders with specific book name.
I am using the following code in my service which returns me the selected book.
How can I retrieve the whole object with filtered book.

```
 this.db.list('/orders')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(mergeMap(x => x))
  .pipe(mergeMap( y => y['items'] as []),
    filter( y => {
      if(y.book.title == "Harry Potter - The Complete Collection")
        return y;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result)); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create separate filter function, that accepts order and filters it buy book name

```
const hasBookByTitle = bookTitle => filter(order => order.items.some(({book}) => book.title === bookTitle))

this.db.list('/orders')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(hasBookByTitle("Harry Potter - The Complete Collection"))
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: I had used this approach to make iteration till book simpler, is there a way in rxjs to directly extract the object with specific field on **items** array

Comment: @Usha.. I'm not sure I understood your question, "extract the object with specific field on items array ". I sometimes use rxjs + lodash.